# Why is the "checked" attribute not true when checkbox is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

In the following code using jQuery:

```js
$("input").change(function(evt) {
  console.log("change event handler invoked", evt);
  console.log($("input").is(':checked'));
  console.log($("input").attr("checked"));
  console.log($("input").prop("checked"));
});

$("input").trigger("click");
$("input").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="the-input" type="checkbox">
```

the `is(':checked')` and `prop("checked")` can both show a true but the `attr("checked") will show undefined.  I thought they are to be the same?  (even if we manually click on the checkbox, it is the same effect).

Also, if I set the `checked` in HTML so that the checkbox is checked by default (http://jsfiddle.net/UcGyM/1/ ), now the `attr("checked")` will print out `checked` for both triggering, so it won't be able to tell whether it is checked or not -- why is that?  (it is also strange that both shows `checked`, but `$("input").attr("checked", true);` or `$("input").attr("checked", false);` can turn it on or off.)

A related question is, if we want to insist on using `attr("checked")`, does that mean in the HTML, it has to have the `checked` attribute: `<input type="checkbox" checked>`, if so, how can it specify the attribute but with it defaulted to off?  (because `checked="false"` or `checked=""` or `checked="0"` will not make it unchecked by default.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) might help.

Comment: attributes aren't always kept in-line with properties, that's why the change to `.attr`/`.prop` was so important and needed.

Comment: Most of the answers to your questions are here http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 5):

No, they are not the same.  `.attr` is the DOM attribute.  It would be `checked` if the element were

```
<input type=checkbox checked>
```

It is the *property* that gets changed when clicked.

As for your related question, `checked` is a boolean attribute so there is no way to specify that an element is not checked while having the checked attribute at all.

I'm not sure why you would want to insist on using `attr` when [the jQuery API itself says this is incorrect as of jQuery 1.6](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)